# GraphQL codegen using GraphQLError type without importing it

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-codegen

This is my codegen config:

```
'generated/graphql-sdk.ts': {
  config: {
    rawRequest: true
  },
  plugins: [
    "typescript",
    "typescript-graphql-request",
    "typescript-operations",
    {
      'fragment-matcher': {
        apolloClientVersion: 3,
        module: "es2015",
        useExplicitTyping: false
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

For some reason the generated graphql-sdk doesn't import GraphQLError causing the typing error, I end up needing to add it in manually.

This only started happening recently but I'm unsure what changed in the code to cause it (config is entirely unchanged).